# xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? as value

Tags: xml

I need to achieve following scenario:

My app.config file should contain something similar to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...nodes...
<Request>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RequestType>
        ...nodes...
    </RequestType>
    ..even more nodes..
</Request>
..nodes...
```

I have this *request* node where data may vary in this particular scenario I need it to be readable xml which will be passed to service, my app fails at runtime obviously claiming that  should be first line of xml doc.

Whole Request will be parsed to string.

Is there way I can achieve it without pushing all nodes under value=""

Comment: use CData? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_cdata_sections.htm

Comment: This might work, i'll check it right away

Comment: Works like a charm, I am not facing runtime errors anymore and I am able to pass this to my service. I am feeling bit ashamed not to think of it myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Keith Hall pointed it out CDATA saves the day, thank you for your quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"

is only allowed once at top of the xml document!
So remove the second occurence.

Comment: I definitely can't do that, its required for request

Comment: So the syntax of you xml is broken which is not supported! Always follow the standards and keep documents clean!

Comment: You could possibly remove the wrong header line with tools like sed or awk before processing! Also you could use HTMLTidy for cleaning your document.

Comment: It is not broken, it's a a requirment, Request node is sen't as a string and stored in database where another service will pick it up and do its business.

Comment: From the view of the xml specification it is broken! And there is no excuse for that! You are doing bad string inserts of one xml document into another - nothing more!

Comment: CDATA handles this, I agree that this isn't best thing to do, but there are always that time when we can't follow best practices. I don't think that creating more xml files will be more neat as I am not in control of Requests they may vary as simple int or soap requests. Anyways thanks for pointing obvious things.

Comment: Best practices is something different than following the rules, because best practices is always within the rules ;-)